# INTERVAL duration literals in TDEngine

Tags: intervals, duration, tdengine

I am [not able to find](https://docs.tdengine.com/taos-sql/interval) duration literals used by INTERVAL keyword in TDEngine. E.g. `select count(*) from mytable interval(1m);` works for 1-minute intervals, but I don't know what letter should be used for 1-month interval. I would like to know all possible duration intervals available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see [source code](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/blob/ef46d2663ae84e16b8f2a6ca7e9983fb861ffb64/src/os/src/detail/osTime.c#L480). It seems TDEngine supports these duration intervals:

```
/*
 * b - nanoseconds;
 * u - microseconds;
 * a - Millionseconds
 * s - Seconds
 * m - Minutes
 * h - Hours
 * d - Days (24 hours)
 * w - Weeks (7 days)
 * n - Months (30 days)
 * y - Years (365 days)
 */
```